# Getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while sending text message to another bluetooth device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am working on an android app where I need to send text over Bluetooth. I have come up with a piece of code to achieve this.My problem is that it crashed after sending the message to the device throwing StringIndexOutOfBoundsException . How can I fix this.My full code is:

```
package com.example.blueremote;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private BluetoothAdapter btadapter;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private Button btnSend;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> foundDevices;
    private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> aa;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private ListView list;
    private TextView tvmsg;
    private static int DISCOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666");
    ImageButton up;
    private String address = "D8:50:E6:8A:16:0F";

    private String text = "up";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Intent disc;
        disc = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        startActivityForResult(disc, DISCOVERY_REQUEST);
        up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_up);

        registerReceiver(discoveryResult, new IntentFilter(
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> connectTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Log.v("Main Activity", " AsyncTask started");
                    BluetoothDevice device = btadapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

                    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                    Log.v("Main Activity", "Socket Created");
                    socket.connect();

                    Log.v("Main Activity", "Socket Connected");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("BLUETOOTH_CLIENT", e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // Log.v("Main Activity", "Invoking switchUI");
                // switchUI();

            }
        };
        connectTask.execute();
        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("Main Activity", "In up Button");
                // Log.v("Main Activity", "Invoking switchUI");
                switchUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void switchUI() {
        Log.v("Main Activity", "In SwitchUI Method");

        Log.v("Main Activity", "Invoking sendMessage Method ");
        sendMessage(socket, text);
        Log.v("Main Activity", "Message Sent");

        BluetoothSocketListener bsl = new BluetoothSocketListener(socket,
                handler);
        Thread messageListener = new Thread(bsl);
        messageListener.start();
    }

    private void sendMessage(BluetoothSocket socket, String msg) {
        msg = "UP";
        OutputStream outStream;
        try {
            Log.v("Main Activity", "Inside sendMessage Method ");

            outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            Log.v("Main Activity", "Outstream:" + outStream);
            byte[] byteString = (msg + " ").getBytes();
            Log.v("Main Activity", "byteString:" + byteString);

            outStream.write(byteString);
            Log.v("Main Activity", "outstream written:");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private class MessagePoster implements Runnable {
        private TextView textView;
        private String message;

        public MessagePoster(String message) {
            // this.textView = textView;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
            // textView.setText(message);
        }
    }

    private class BluetoothSocketListener implements Runnable {
        private BluetoothSocket socket;
        private TextView textView;
        private Handler handler;

        public BluetoothSocketListener(BluetoothSocket socket, Handler handler) {
            this.socket = socket;
            // this.textView = textView;
            this.handler = handler;
        }

        public void run() {
            int bufferSize = 2048;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            try {
                InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();
                int bytesRead = -1;
                String message = "";
                while (true) {
                    message = "";
                    bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
                    if (bytesRead != -1) {
                        while ((bytesRead == bufferSize)
                                && (buffer[bufferSize - 1] != 0)) {
                            message = message
                                    + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
                        }
                        message = message
                                + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
                        handler.post(new MessagePoster(message));
                        socket.getInputStream();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("BLUETOOTH_COMMS", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            BluetoothDevice remoteDevice;
            remoteDevice = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (btadapter.getBondedDevices().contains(remoteDevice)) {
                foundDevices.add(remoteDevice);
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(discoveryResult);
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10360): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1585

E/AndroidRuntime(10360): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2048; regionStart=0; regionLength=65534

E/AndroidRuntime(10360):    at java.lang.String.failedBoundsCheck(String.java:587)

E/AndroidRuntime(10360):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:247)

E/AndroidRuntime(10360):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:171)

E/AndroidRuntime(10360):    at com.example.blueremote.MainActivity$BluetoothSocketListener.run(MainActivity.java:177)
```

Comment: And which line is MainActivity.java:177?

Comment: @immibis:while (true) {
     message = "hello";
     bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
     if (bytesRead != -1) {
      while ((bytesRead == bufferSize)
        && (buffer[bufferSize - 1] != 0)) {
       message = message
         + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
      }
      message = message
        + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
      handler.post(new MessagePoster(message));
      socket.getInputStream();
     }
    }

Comment: try using string buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to the `String` class, we see that calling `String (byte[] data, int offset, int byteCount)` will throw a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when one of three scenarios occur:

1. `offset > 0` -  if the offset passed to the method is less than 0, an `Exception` will be thrown. Since you pass `0` and and not a variable to your method call, this is not causing the `Exception`.
2. `offset + byteCount > data.length` - in this scenario an `Exception` will be thrown when `offset` plus `byteCount` is larger than the length of the buffer. In your code, `offset` is always `0` and `byteCount`, which in your example is `bytesRead - 1`, can never exceed `2048`, since `instream.read(buffer)` cannot read more bytes than `buffer` itself can hold. This means that `offset` (0) + `byteCount` (-1 ≤ `byteCount` ≤ 2047) will never be greater than `data.length` (2048), so this is not the cause of the `Exception`.
3. `byteCount < 0` - the third scenario that will throw the mentioned `Exception` is when you pass a `byte` count that is less than `0`. In your example, you pass `bytesRead - 1` as the `byte` count. While you check to make sure that `bytesRead != -1`, which will occur if the end of the stream has been reached, you do not check to make sure that at least 1 `byte` was read. This is most likely the culprit...

Per your example, let us consider what happens when `bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);` returns `0`, meaning no `byte`s were read...

1. The first check you perform, `if (bytesRead != -1)`, will pass, since `bytesRead` is equal to `0`.
2. Inside the `if` statement is `while ((bytesRead == bufferSize) && (buffer[bufferSize - 1] != 0))`, which will of course also fail since `bytesRead`, which is `0`, is not equal to `bufferSize`, which is `2048`.
3. The final call is `message = message + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);`, which we can translate to `message = message + String(buffer, 0, -1)`. As you can see, since `bytesRead` was 0, the above call will generate `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To fix this issue simply make sure that you do not call `String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1)` if `bytesRead` is less than `1`.